# Issue with Pagination with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination with MVC.

My Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]


        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            int pageSize = 2;
            int PageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return PartialView(new UserListModel
            {
                userModel = Repo.GetUsers().OrderBy(x=>x.FullName).ToPagedList(PageNumber, pageSize),
                ddlDept = Repo.GetPairModel("Dept")
            });
        }
```

My Index.cshtml:

```
    @model PagedList.IPagedList<UserListModel>
    @using PagedList.Mvc;
    ----
     @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                 -----------
                }
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", 
    new { page }))
```

But I am having following issue:

```
    The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'UserListModel', but this
 dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[UserListModel]'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my Problem with following steps:

Model

```
 public class UserListModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<PairModel> ddlDept { get; set; }
        public PagedList.IPagedList<UserTbl> userModel { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@model UserListModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    PagedList.IPagedList<UserTbl> userListModel = Model.userModel;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert UserListModel as IPagedList, not the inner userModel property of it. Your view expects IPagedList not IPagedList

Comment: How to convert UserListModel as IPagedList. Can you help with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning `UserListModel` to a view which is expecting `IPagedList<UserListModel>`

change this

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<UserListModel>
```

To

```
@model UserListModel
```

Comment: But I also need to have pagination.